# How to define path and formData parameters for the same operation in OpenAPI 2.0?

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, openapi, swagger-editor

I have an image upload endpoint that looks like `/test/{id}/relationships/image`. I want to describe this endpoint using OpenAPI 2.0 (Swagger 2.0).

The endpoint has both path and formData parameters. I tried the following:

```yaml
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: API
  version: 1.0.0
host: api.server.de
schemes:
  - https
produces:
  - application/json
paths:
  '/test/{id}/relationships/image':
    post:
      operationId: addImage
      consumes:
        - multipart/form-data
      parameters:
        - in: path
          name: id
          required: true
          schema:
            type: integer
            format: int32
        - in: formData
          name: file
          type: file
          required: true
          description: The file to upload.
        - in: formData
          name: metadata
          type: string
          required: false
          description: Description of file contents.
      responses:
        '202':
          description: Uploaded
```

But Swagger Editor shows errors:

> Schema error at
>   paths['/test/{id}/relationships/image'].post.parameters[0].in should
>   be equal to one of the allowed values allowedValues: body, header,
>   formData, query Jump to line 17
>
> Schema error at
>   paths['/test/{id}/relationships/image'].post.parameters[0] should NOT
>   have additional properties additionalProperty: schema, in, name,
>   required Jump to line 17

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In your path parameter, change

```
          schema:
            type: integer
            format: int32
```

to

```
          type: integer
          format: int32
```

In OpenAPI/Swagger 2.0, path, header, query and formData parameters use `type` directly, without a `schema`. The `schema` keyword is used for body parameters only.

Comment: thank you very much, that's helps. it's weird because the docs said something different https://swagger.io/docs/specification/paths-and-operations/ look at the '/users/{id}:' example and on this example also it uses the schema paramter https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/

Comment: Those docs are for OpenAPI 3.0, as indicated by the note at the top. The 2.0 versions are swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/paths-and-operations/ and https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/describing-parameters/

Comment: Helped me though I wanted it in the reverse way :) I was on 3.0