# How to define an operation with both body and header parameters in OpenAPI 2.0?

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, openapi, swagger-editor

How can a OpenAPI 2.0 (Swagger 2.0) definition have a body and a header parameter in the same operation? I tried the following:

```yaml
  /image-correction:
    post:
      operationId: image-correction_create
      tags:
        - image-corrections
      consumes:
        - application/json
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - in: body
          name: requestBody
          description: imageCorrection
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/ImageCorrection'
        - in: header
          name: X-Request-ID
          schema:
            type: string
            format: uuid
          required: true
```

but Swagger Editor shows an error:

> should NOT have additional properties additionalProperty: schema

Comment: Related (or duplicate): [How to define path and formData parameters for the same operation in OpenAPI 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45534187/113116)

Answer (score 1):

In OpenAPI 2.0, header, query, and path parameters do not use `schema`, they use `type` directly. Change your header parameter as follows:

```yaml
    - in: header
      name: X-Request-ID
      type: string     # <----
      format: uuid     # <----
      required: true
```

This was changed in OpenAPI 3.0 (`openapi: 3.0.0`) where all parameter types use `schema`.

Comment: Thank you ! my header only has Accept, Content-Type and Authorization. but the doc says "Header parameters named Accept, Content-Type and Authorization are not allowed. To describe these headers, use the corresponding OpenAPI keywords:" how should I state them ?

Comment: `Authorization` is described as a [security scheme](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/authentication/), i.e. using `securityDefinitions`+`security`. `Content-Type` is defined using `produces`, and `Accept` - using `consumes`.